# Open another sweet alert 2 after the first close

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Actually i want to show many sweet alerts.

Example: I have a backpanel to config my sweetalert then i save it, in my database i have many data:

```
id estatus  title            description        date_in       date_from
1    1     mensaje 1       texto mensaje 1     8/12/2020      9/12/2020
2    1     mensaje 2       texto mensaje 2     8/12/2020      9/12/2020
```

Then in frontpage when page load, the first sweet alert show it but when i clik in ok button, the second sweet alert don´t show.

My problem is in each function... when the first data is in the each just read the data but not show, after read the second data and then show the second data in modal.

Sweetalert not show the first data when is in each function.

Somebody know the reason?

Thanks.

```
require(['core/first', 'jquery', 'jqueryui', 'core/ajax'], function (core, $, bootstrap, ajax) {
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "local/frontmessage/messagedata.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { getData: 'getData' },
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            var configuracion = obj[0];
            var sessionUser = obj[1];
            var estadoTitulo = false;
            var estadoDesc = false;
            var estadoBtnAceptar = false;
            var estadoBtnCancelar = false;
            var estadoBtnClose = false;
            var estadoImagen = false;
            var visto = 0;
    
    
            $.each(configuracion, function (key, objF) {
              if (objF["estado_titulo"] == "1") {
                estadoTitulo = true;
              }
              else if (objF["estado_titulo"] == "0") {
                estadoTitulo = false;
              }
              if (objF["estado_descripcion"] == "1") {
                estadoDesc = true;
              }
              else if (objF["estado_descripcion"] == "0") {
                estadoDesc = false;
              }
              if (objF["estado_btn_aceptar"] == "1") {
                estadoBtnAceptar = true;
              }
              else if (objF["estado_btn_aceptar"] == "0") {
                estadoBtnAceptar = false;
              }
              if (objF["estado_btn_cancelar"] == "1") {
                estadoBtnCancelar = true;
              }
              else if (objF["estado_btn_cancelar"] == "0") {
                estadoBtnCancelar = false;
              }
              if (objF["estado_btn_x"] == "1") {
                estadoBtnClose = true;
              }
              else if (objF["estado_btn_x"] == "0") {
                estadoBtnClose = false;
              }
              if (objF["estado_imagen"] == "1") {
                estadoImagen = true;
              }
              else if (objF["estado_imagen"] == "0") {
                estadoImagen = false;
              }
    
              // Sweetalert con aceptar o cancelar
              const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
                customClass: {
                  confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
                  cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger',
                },
                buttonsStyling: false
              })
              //  Inicio de sweet
              swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
                html: true,
                width: objF["tamanio_mensaje"],
                allowEscapeKey: false,
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                allowEnterKey: false,
                title: objF["texto_titulo"],
                html: objF["texto_descripcion"],
                // Video youtube
                // html: '<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;autoplay=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>',
                // icon: 'warning',
                showConfirmButton: estadoBtnAceptar,
                showCancelButton: estadoBtnCancelar,
                confirmButtonText: objF["texto_btn_aceptar"],
                cancelButtonText: objF["texto_btn_cancelar"],
                reverseButtons: false,
                showCloseButton: estadoBtnClose,
                imageUrl: objF["url_imagen"],
                imageWidth: objF["ancho_imagen"],
                imageHeight: objF["alto_imagen"],
                imageAlt: objF["descripcion_imagen"],
              })
                .then((result) => {
                  if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                      objF["texto_btn_aceptar"],
                      objF["mensaje_btn_aceptar"],
                      'success'
                    );
                  } else if (
                    /* Read more about handling dismissals below */
                    result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
                  ) {
                    swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                      objF["texto_btn_cancelar"],
                      objF["mensaje_btn_cancelar"],
                      'error'
                    );
                  }
                })
              // fin de sweet
            });
            // fin de eeach
          }
      });

})
```

})

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: Thanks Guerric i posted the code, my problem is in each function, in each function have all data, but only show the last data.